# CheckedListBox Select All Items - Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox that when a checked checks all items in a `CheckedListBox`.
When the checkbox goes unchecked it should uncheck all items in the list.

Code:

```
 if (checkBoxCheckAllPrivileges.Checked)
   for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items.Count; i++)
      checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.SetItemChecked(i, true);
 else
   for (int i = 0; i < listBoxUsers.Items.Count; i++)
    checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.SetItemChecked(i, false);
```

Is the problem in this code? 

Does the **.SetitemChecked** work giving it the parameter as false?

**Is there any other way to uncheck the items?**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @user3185569 
the code is in the  checkBoxCheckAllPrivileges_CheckedChanged 
there's no more code in the event handler and the debugger goes through the code like a charm

Comment: You could improve the algorithm by just replacing the if/else by the for and `checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.SetItemChecked(i, checkBoxCheckAllPrivileges.Checked);`

Comment: If you create an extension method named `SetItemsChecked(bool)` it would be more reusable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given wrong item in else part for loop,

```
if (checkBoxCheckAllPrivileges.Checked)
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items.Count; i++)
        checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.SetItemChecked(i, true);
else
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items.Count; i++)
        checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.SetItemChecked(i, false);
```

Comment: sowjanya attaluri lol omg thanks i'm facing this error for an hour now... long night thanks for the keen eye

Comment: You could avoid the if statement with just `checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.SetItemChecked(i, checkBoxCheckAllPrivileges.Checked);`

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript Too

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#<%=checkBoxCheckAllPrivileges.ClientID%>").click(function () {

if ($(this).is(":checked"))

 {

  $("#<%=checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.ClientID%> input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);

  }

 else

 {


$("#<%=checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.ClientID%> input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);


 }


 });
```

Comment: araving this is winforms, How could use java-script to do this ?

Comment: Not directly, but you can write/use an existing framework that handles this for you, and write some bindings to your UI or something. I've used http://jurassic.codeplex.com/ in the past, and its proven very efficient.

Comment: Refer this Eldho.....http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127356/Calling-JavaScript-function-from-WinForms-and-vice

Comment: Sure it may work , But i dont think its worth to use another library to do this

Comment: The code project thing is different from your jurassic framework iit use webbrowser component to show the webpage .

Comment: refer last link Eldho